# How do i get day difference between 2 dates?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the code below to calculate the days difference between 2 dates. First view is where i pick a date from **UIDatePicker()** , press a button to segue to the second view and to calculate days difference between the selected date and today's date and pass the result to the second view to be shown.

I just cant get the function to calculate the time difference to work. Is there something wrong im doing? 
Im sorry in advance as i've just started learning swift.

on my code

```
Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self.GetDate,to: datePicker.date).day!
```

i get this error below

> Type 'Any' has no member 'day'

-

**first view.**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateInput: UITextField!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    var GetDate = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CreateDatePicker()
    }

    // Create Date
    func CreateDatePicker() {
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        dateInput.inputView = datePicker
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(doneClicked))
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
        dateInput.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }

    @objc func doneClicked() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        dateInput.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }


    @IBAction func GetDateButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.GetDate = dateInput.text!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTime", sender: self)
        Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self.GetDate,to: datePicker.date).day!
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! timeDiffr
        vc.textDisplay = self.GetDate
    }
}
```

**Second view**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class timeDiffr: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labeltext: UILabel!

    var textDisplay = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labeltext.text = textDisplay
    }

}
```

Comment: It's best to keep your question focused to one issue. Please update your question so it is only about the error trying to use `dateComponents`.

Comment: You need a `Date` for the `from` parameter. You are trying to give it a `String`.

Comment: @rmaddy how can someone figure an issue without seeing the whole picture? Also, the issue is only with this line as im struggling to find a fix. I noticed im passing string, but im lost on which date to pass. Even with datePicker is not working.

Comment: `Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self.GetDate,to: datePicker.date).day!` , please notice that
`from` should be an instance of `Date`, not a `String` @MustafaAljaburi

Comment: @MustafaAljaburi Instead of passing the string, you can convert that string into date and pass. `dateComponents` method takes 2 dates, so you need to pass a `Date` instead of string

Comment: You already asked this and it was closed as a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58109254/how-to-get-days-difference-between-two-dates How is this different?

Comment: @matt i found a solution, but its not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should notice about your coding convention

- Variable, function names should be in camel case: `GetDate`shoud be `getDate`, `GetDateButton` should be `getDateButton`, `CreateDatePicker` should be `createDatePicker`

And your `getDate` is a string while         `Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self.GetDate,to: datePicker.date).day!` return an int value. That's the problem you need to fix.

You `GetDateButton` function should be:

```
@IBAction func GetDateButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // Get distance by day (intValue)
    let distanceInDay = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: datePicker.date).day!
}
```

Comment: About the camelCase. This is just like a playground im testing this specific problem with and i need to find a fix before implementing the solution to the final project which will be different for sure. and for the getDate, i noticed im passing a string, but even with " Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: datePicker,to: Date).day!" is not working. Im sorry, but im just practicing and learning swift.

Comment: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self.GetDate,to: datePicker.date).day! , please notice that from should be an instance of Date, not a String @MustafaAljaburi

Comment: BTW, no problem for sure, just wanna help you to have a good coding convention from beginning :) @MustafaAljaburi

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can get the distance in day (intValue) like that, if you wan a string then convert `distanceInDay` to string (e.g: `let stringValue = String(distanceInDay)` @MustafaAljaburi